# How to query firestore from the command line as admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I authenticate as admin from the command line to dump out / query the data in my firestore? Example, I have a `users` collection where each document looks like:

```
{
  edit_count: 15
}
```

I simply want to print all these documents as json in my terminal.

I've used firebase-tools, but it looks like it's only supporting querying of the RTDB?

Comment: Yup as mentioned in answers due to firestore being in beta, the feature you're looking doesn't exist at the moment. A workaround for now would be to apply filters (which uses queries underneath) in the firebase console. Although this cannot perform complex queries at the moment.

Answer (score 15):

While waiting for firebase-tools to support more firestore commands, I wrote a basic firestore client that you might find useful:

https://github.com/sgarciac/fuego

Answer (score 12):

At the moment (July 2018)  [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) supports [database commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands) (get, set, push etc etc) only for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) probably due to Firestore beeing in beta.

Hopefully it will support it later.

Comment: I can't find any examples of how to actually use this

Comment: @marco.marinangeli not yet, but firestore came out of beta this month...

Comment: One year later not yet?

Comment: Still no proper cli interface for firestore! I had to write a small python script to list all the collections.

Comment: It is very disappointed since in many causes you want to preform a one time, very basic query, and each time you have to deploy a function for it.

Comment: 4 year later, still no way to query firestore from command line. If you want information on a specific field of a specific document, the only way is the console, which is quite cumbersome. What a shit show

Answer (score -13):

Read the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

This will teach you how to set up local auth to your firestore data.

Comment: It might be helpful here to indicate that the Firebase CLI does not support querying, getting, or putting to Firestore at this time in Beta.

Comment: Just to add to the previous comment, Firestore is well out of Beta and at the time it still doesn't support querying, getting or putting through CLI